# G Suite Developer Hubでのトリガーの追加ができない，Google Apps Script, GAS, Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Formでアンケートを作って，その内容をスプレッドシートの中に書き込み，メール添付で返す処理をスクリプトエディタで書いています。

G Suite Developer Hubがリリースされる前に作成したスクリプトで，少なくとも半年前は動作していましたが，久しぶりに実行したら動作しませんでした。メール添付で送られてきませんでした。ログを確認したところ，全くスクリプトが動作していないことが分かったので，一旦，トリガーを削除し再作成を試みたのですが，画像のように，エラーになります。

エラー　ページを再読込して，もう一度お試しください。
スクリプトの承認に失敗しました。ポップアップブロッカーの設定を確認してもう一度お試しください。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

それで，ブラウザのキャッシュやクッキーをクリアしましたがダメ。ブラウザの再起動もだめ，パソコンの再起動もダメ，Chromeでなく普段使ってないieを使ってもダメ。パソコンを替えてもダメでした。

どなたか，アドバイス頂けませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらをご参照ください。
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95472?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=ja

ポップアップとリダイレクトを許可にして、再度トリガーを設定してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。すでに試してダメでしたが，もう一度じっくりと確認してみます。

Comment: 既にお試しでしたのですね。申し訳ありません。では、エラー発生時に、別のGoogleアカウントでログインしていないかご確認ください。自分も同事象になった際に、全てのGoogleアカウントをログオフして再度実行したらうまくいった経験があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。それもやっています。普段使ってない，ieでログインして試してもダメでした。なんとなく，Google側の問題じゃないかと思っています。おそらく新しくフォームを作成すればできると思うので･･･。最悪，新規に作り直そうかと思ってます。

Comment: 色々お試しなのですね…トリガー設定の前に、スクリプトエディタ上でデバッグを行い、先に権限付与（恐らくGmailへの権限）を行ってからトリガー設定してみるとどうなりますかね？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
フォルダコピーツールを使って丸ごとコピーしてトリガーを追加してもだめ，当該フォームを単独コピーしてもだめ。
結局，同じフォームをゼロから作り直して，スクリプトもそのままコピーして，トリガーを追加したら，うまくいきました。
こちらでは操作できない部分（サーバサイド）でおかしくなってたような印象です。
トリガーの設定UIが変わってから，動作してないことに気がつきました。あとから届いたエラーは，submitFormが見つからないなどと言う，あり得ないエラーでした。
トリガーを一旦削除したら，追加できなくなったので，サーバ側の問題か，私がまだ理解していない，何かの設定かもしれません。
いろいろ丁寧にアドバイスいただき，ありがとうございました。